# PHP exec() with CUDA

Tags: php, cuda

```
exec("fun.exe input/input.txt ");
```

I want to run an CUDA program in PHP,
the task is:

1. load data from an input.txt.  (argument)
2. calculating.
3. write an output.txt.

and PHP read ouput.txt to do next task.

In server1(Apache ,Windows XP), it can run perfectly,
but in server2,3(Apache, Windows 7),the output is wrong.
The program doesn't crash and there's no any error message in the page,
it seems like something wrong during the execution.
Next I try exec the All CPU-side version (same calculation),server2,3 can run correctly.
If I exec the fun.exe(CUDA version) in server2,3 directly(double click or in command line),the program also run perfectly.

Any idea on why server2,3 can't run the program? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case, this occurs because Apache (installed together with XAMPP) was started as a service. If I run Apache directly, instead of as a service, CUDA works. Is there any solution to this problem(Apache as a service and CUDA)??

Answer (score 1):

First, try using the full path to the executable. Then the full path to the input file too.
If that doesn't work, then try modifying the file permissions (try with full 777 permissions, if that works then you know where your problem lies).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Full path doesn't work. How to change permission under the Windows7? I right click the top web app folder(try) and cancel the read only option. exec("C:\\AppServ\\www\\try\\fun.exe C:\\AppServ\\www\\try\\testD\\input.txt");

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the entire path (windows version using backslash).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use the entire path and get the same result. exec("C:\\AppServ\\www\\try\\fun.exe C:\\AppServ\\www\\try\\testD\\input.txt");